# Android let app know that media was mounted/unmounted while app was destroyed

Tags: android, mediastore

Is there a way to let my app know that Media (SDCard) was mounted/unmounted while my app was turned off? I mean that my app and its services were Destroyed, not only stopped.
Probably, some ways to check MediaStore checksum are available?

Goal: decide if new music files were added or deleted in device memory to refresh general playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not check if the SDCARD is mounted by using `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` upon restarting your app? The value you want it to be is `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED`. You could do it async and display a message somewhere stating that an update is in progress, however...

...if it's really the callback-ish thing you need, then you'll have to have a look at [what John Willis wrote about registering a BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033464/860212).

Comment: But better to register Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED - when MediaStore is already updated

Comment: Good to know for future use. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have register a broadcast receiver to receive an intent 
     android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED

Comment: thanks, its right idea, but it's better to register Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED - when MediaStore is already updated

Comment: I think that answer by @ninetwozero is more informative, so I've accepted it. But I put "useful answer" for your advice. Thanks again!